# How to replace a substring within double parentheses in Java?

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I need to replace a substring within double parentheses with an empty one. I use:
 `source = source.replaceAll("\(.+?\)", "");`

The substrings within single parentheses are removed. Instead, when I try with a substring within double parentheses the entire substring is removed but the last ')' remains.
What's wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post examples. It's much easier to follow the specifics if you say, "When my code's input is [blob of text], I want the output to be [this other blob of text]."

Comment: Do you mean change `blah ((yakkety)) something` into `blah (()) something` OR do you mean change `blah (yackittee) other-thing` into `blah other-thing`??? or where in between??

Comment: I mean change blah ((yakkety)) in blah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The +? means that your match is going to take the *least* amount of characters possible, meaning that it will grab the inner parenthesized statement.

Try:

```
source = source.replaceAll("\(?\(.+?\)\)?", "");
```

I've just wrapped your regex with `\(?` and `\)?`.

Comment: It works. Sometimes it's more simple than it seems.  
Thank you Dave

Comment: Awesome!  You could mark this as the answer if you were definitely good. : )

Answer (score 1):

`source.replaceAll("\(\([^\(]*\)\)", "");` ?

(not tested)